# Displaying image in php

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I'm trying to display an image from the database i created, using phpmyadmin to test my script. The database contains images in png and jpg. But the output are just nonsense characters because the browser cannot render the image. Can some one tell me where I get wrong?

I google the problem and I can see their pattern and mine are similar so I don't really under stand where I get wrong. I can get the name of the image in database, but not the image.

this is my script:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Dave", "password");
if (!$con){
    die ("Could not connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_select_db($con, "snippet");

$res = mysqli_query($con, "select * from image");

echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; echo $row["image_name"]; echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does $row["image"] contain...? URL or something else...?

Comment: Check your folder structure.. I think your code getting image name only from the database. You should append with your image folder name. 
For Example: Image path: /images/123.jpg then you should write your code like this
<img src="<?php echo 'images/'.$row["image"]; ?>" height="100" width="100">

Comment: don't store images in a database. that's insane. if you are afraid the complexity of image uploads, its pretty simple with `php_exif` and `libgd` installed. check out https://github.com/bivoc/bulletproof for a class that will accomplish reasonably secure image uploads with only a few lines of code.

Comment: It's not insane. It's just less common/popular than the alternative.

Comment: @Orion: da vang anh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What format is your imaged stored as?
Raw bytes?
Base-64?
or a URL?

If it's a URL then just use the attribute 'src' of the html img element.

If it's Base-64 then use

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,THE BASE 64 code here" />
```

If you have raw bytes, either convert them to Base-64 with PHP

```
$base64segment = base64_encode($data);
```

or you can call a custom url within the src attribute that will lead to a PHP script where you can create an image on the fly from the bytes by sending a custom header followed by the bytes:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data));
echo $data;
?>
```

The disadvantage of the Base-64 based approach is that the data takes more space than the original binary segment because the encoding is done using 64 different signs instead of 256.

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
 <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>
```

You are setting the source of the image. This should be either an URL or a path from your server root. What I usually did was save the file location and name (so for example "/images/imagename.png") in the database.

If you used MIME type or BLOB in the database, this code will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$base64 = 'data:image/PNG;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']);
 echo "<img src=$base64 />" ;
```

In your code...

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>"; ?> <img src="<?php echo data:image/PNG;base64,'. base64_encode($row["image"]); ?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
echo "<td>"; echo $row["image_name"]; echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Dave", "password");
if (!$con){
    die ("Could not connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_select_db($con, "snippet");

$res = mysqli_query($con, "select * from image");

echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
$row["image"] = "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($row["image"]); //the trick!
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; echo $row["image_name"]; echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You answer is ok, But instead of posting entire code, Just try to fix the error the questioner has.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store image `MIME type` in database, then you can display image like this:

```
echo $row["image"];
header("Content-Type: ".$row['mime_type']);
```

For example, `PNG`'s `MIME type` is `image/png`;